# Best way to synchronize MySQL bases on different servers

Tags: mysql, synchronization, replication, database-replication

I have two servers. One is located in our office, and its MySQL base contains our offers, our clients etc.

The second server is located at our hosting provider's datacenter. It uses the same database structure and the same offers, and I use it for our website.

I was synchronizing these two servers manually, by sending json from one server to another each few hours, but now I need a real-time synchronization.

Which way should I use?

1. Master-slave replication from company server to website server. The problem is, that our slave website database has its own changeable tables too. For example, orders, user sessions, viewcounts and so on. And I need to send somehow that tables to master server at office.
2. To use only one database for both servers. Problem is, that there could be up to 100 queries each pageview, and I think that running each query through internet could be quiet slow.

We cannot use only one server for all tasks because we are unable to provide a stable low-latency internet connection in our office. So when internet is down, our site or our CRM system would be down to.

May be there is a third and best way to do this?

Comment: This will be helpful for others:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36354/how-to-sync-mysql-database-between-two-servers

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Data Comparison tool](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/database-synchronization.html) in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/). It will connect to two different MySQL servers (using simple connection, SSL, SSH or HTTP tunnel), compare them and show differences; then it will offer to run synchronization script or view/save it.

There is also stand-alone [dbForge Data Compare](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/datacompare/) tool.